# api fetching works in chrome brower, but doesn't work in terminal using "curl"

Tags: api, curl

I'm trying to use [open weather API](https://openweathermap.org/api), I just created an account and got my API key, after I wrote *https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=<--myapikey-->*

in zsh, it returns:

> [1] 12567 zsh: no matches found:
> https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London
> jack@jackengtwistios-Mac-mini node-andrew %  [1]  + exit 1     curl
> https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London

in bash:

> [1] 12715 jackengtwistios-Mac-mini:node-andrew jack$ {"cod":401,
> "message": "Invalid API key. Please see
> http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}

but in chrome brower it just returns the expected result:

> {"coord":{"lon":-0.1257,"lat":51.5085},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear
> sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":279.99,"feels_like":279.99,"temp_min":278.87,"temp_max":280.86,"pressure":1017,"humidity":72},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":0.45,"deg":331,"gust":2.24},"clouds":{"all":7},"dt":1637851503,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2019646,"country":"GB","sunrise":1637825718,"sunset":1637856008},"timezone":0,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

Comment: "Invalid API key" - where in your CURL are you passing the api key?

Answer (score 0):

OP shows that this URL works in Chrome:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=<--myapikey-->
```

But this is what is being used in cURL

```
curl https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London
```

It's missing the appid parameter